# Umbraco project fails to build unless I install Smidge.Nuglify and Smidge.InMemory

Tags: umbraco

Every time I clone an Umbraco project from the cloud, I have to install `Smidge.Nuglify` and `Smidge.InMemory` to get the project run successfully from Visual Studio 2022. How can I avoid that? Why is this happening to me?

[image]